# How to insert Data into the Computed Columns using ADF V1

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

How can we insert data into the computed columns using ADF V1. Currently we cannot insert the data into the Azure SQL Database.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean computed columns? Could you post more details about your issue? Insert what data? What type?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation and also looking for a better solution.
I am copying data from a prod db and updating the QA db with it.

Here's how I have been handling it so far: modify the hashbytes column in the target QA db table so that it is a varchar. But this solution is less than ideal because this will have to be done manually every single time a code change is pushed to the affected table.

Your situation is different.
If it were me, I would do a straight copy of the data into the Azure SQL Database. No computed tables. No modifications. Then I would stage the data into another table that had the computed columns I was after.
It is an Extract, Load, Transform approach, compared to the traditional Extract, Transform, Load method.

This question is really old, but hey, I found this question just now; maybe other will, too.